# SQL- auto insert custom record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to auto insert custom record in a column field (**caseNum**) in MSSQL.

custom Field should have last two digits of the current year  **21** and reset incremental counter to **Zero(0)** at the beginning of each year like this :-

**caseNum**
21-01
21-02
21-03

So next year it should be

**caseNum**
22-01
22-02
22-03

This is what currently I have started with. Not sure if it is right.

```sql
GO <br>
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[caseNumberTrigger]<br> 
ON [dbo].[BYLAW] <br>
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE <br> 
AS <br>
BEGIN <br>
    UPDATE Y <br>  
    SET [casenum] = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(10)) + CAST(i.id AS NVARCHAR(20))  <br>
    FROM BYLAW Y <br>
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON Y.id = i.id <br>
END<br>
```

I will highly appreciate your help! Thank You

Comment: Do you have some SQL to give us a starting point?

Comment: What happens if a row is deleted? Seems like this might be better served in a `VIEW` using  `ROW_NUMBER` on a sequential ID and partitioned on a column to denote the year.

Comment: Put your attempt in your qusetion, @AnkushGoyal using the [edit] feature. T-SQL, however, doesn't support HTML Break lines (`<br>`).

Comment: @Larnu It should delete with a deleted row.

Comment: But what happens to the sequence?

Comment: @Larnu It should not affect sequence for example if record is 21-2, 21-3 and if 21-2 is deleted it should continue with auto incremental 21-4.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you need some `SEQUENCE` s then.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. How can I reset to zero starting each year?